# Deadlock with MPI

Tags: mpi, deadlock

I'm experimenting with MPI and was wondering if this code could cause a deadlock.

```
MPI_Comm_rank (comm, &my_rank);
if (my_rank == 0) {
   MPI_Send (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm);
   MPI_Recv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm, &status);
} else if (my_rank == 1) {
   MPI_Send (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm);
   MPI_Recv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm, &status);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`MPI_Send` may or may not block. It will block until the sender can reuse the sender buffer. Some implementations will return to the caller when the buffer has been sent to a lower communication layer. Some others will return to the caller when there's a matching `MPI_Recv()` at the other end. So it's up to your MPI implementation whether if this program will deadlock or not.

Because of this program behaves differently among different MPI implementations, you may consider rewritting it so there won't be possible deadlocks:

```
MPI_Comm_rank (comm, &my_rank);
if (my_rank == 0) {
   MPI_Send (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm);
   MPI_Recv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm, &status);
} else if (my_rank == 1) {
   MPI_Recv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm, &status);
   MPI_Send (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm);
}
```

Always be aware that for every `MPI_Send()` there must be a pairing `MPI_Recv()`, both "parallel" in time. For example, this may end in deadlock because pairing send/recv calls are not aligned in time. They cross each other:

```
RANK 0                          RANK 1
----------                      -------
MPI_Send() ---            ----  MPI_Send()    |
              ---      ---                    |
                 ------                       |
                   --                         | TIME
                 ------                       |
              ---      ---                    |
MPI_Recv() <--            --->  MPI_Recv()    v
```

These processes, on the other way, won't end in deadlock, provided of course, that there are indeed two processes with ranks 0 and 1 in the same communicator domain.

```
RANK 0                          RANK 1
----------                      -------
MPI_Send() ------------------>  MPI_Recv()   |
                                             | TIME
                                             |
MPI_Recv() <------------------  MPI_Send()   v
```

The above fixed program may fail if the size of the communicator `com` does not allow rank 1 (only 0). That way, the `if-else` won't take the `else` route and thus, no process will be listening for the `MPI_Send()` and rank 0 will deadlock.

If you need to use your current communication layout, then you may prefer to use `MPI_Isend()` or `MPI_Issend()` instead for nonblocking sends, thus avoiding deadlock.

Comment: New to MPI, but I guess ... for every MPI_Send() there must be a pairing MPI_Recv(), both "parallel" in time. is not always true. If data needs to be sent to all processes and process 0 has the default access (e.g., stdin), then there will be no paired Recv() for process 0.

Answer (score 7):

The post by @mcleod_ideafix is very good. I want to add a couple more things about non-blocking MPI calls.

The way most MPI implementations is that they copy the data out of the user buffer into some other place. It might be a buffer internal to the implementation, it might be something better on the right kind of networks. When that data is copied out of the user buffer and the buffer can be reused by the application, the `MPI_SEND` call returns. This may be before the matching `MPI_RECV` is called or it may not. The larger the data you are sending, the more likely that your message will block until the `MPI_RECV` call is made.

The best way to avoid this is to use non-blocking calls `MPI_IRECV` and `MPI_ISEND`. This way you can post your `MPI_IRECV` first, then make your call to `MPI_ISEND`. This avoids extra copies when the messages arrive (because the buffer to hold them is already available via the `MPI_IRECV`) which makes things faster, and it avoids the deadlock situation. So now your code would look like this:

```
MPI_Comm_rank (comm, &my_rank);
if (my_rank == 0) {
   MPI_Irecv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm, &status, &requests[0]);
   MPI_Isend (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 1, tag, comm, &requests[1]);
} else if (my_rank == 1) {
   MPI_Irecv (recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm, &status, &requests[0]);
   MPI_Isend (sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, comm, &requests[1]);
}
MPI_Waitall(2, request, &statuses);
```

Answer (score 3):

As mcleod_ideafix explained your code can result in a deadlock.
Here you go: [Explanation and two possible issue Solutions, one by rearranging execution order, one by async send recv calls](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_mpi/mpi_race_conditions.html)

Heres the solution with async calls:

```
if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_Isend(..., 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
        MPI_Recv(..., 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Wait(&req, &status);
} else if (rank == 1) {
        MPI_Recv(..., 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(..., 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```