# MPI_send and MPI_receive function getting stuck

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have a code of page_rank where I have to compute page rank in parallel. My code hangs where I wrote the following MPI_send and MPI_receive function. What could be the problem?

```
int **sendto_list = (int **)malloc(comm_size*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0; i < comm_size; i++) {
    sendto_list[i] = (int *)malloc(18*sizeof(int));
    sendto_list[i][0] = 16;
    sendto_list[i][1] = 0;
}

int temp_data = 1;
for(i=0; i < comm_size; i++) {
    if(request_list[i][1] > 0) {
        for(k=0; k < request_list[i][1]; ) {
            for(j=0; j < 200; j++) {
                if( k >= request_list[i][1] )
                        break;

                sendrecv_buffer_int[j] = request_list[i][k+2];
                k++;
            }
            // Request appropriate process for pagerank.
            if(i!= my_rank)
                MPI_Send(&temp_data, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG_PR_REQ, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }

    if( i != my_rank )
        MPI_Send(&temp_data, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG_PR_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

int expected_requests = 0, done = 0,temp,s;
s=0;
while( (done == 0) && (comm_size > 1) ) {
    if(expected_requests == (comm_size - 1))
        break;

    int count;
    // Receive pagerank requests or messages with TAG_PR_DONE(can be from any process).
    MPI_Recv(&temp, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE ,MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);

    switch(status.MPI_TAG) {
        case TAG_PR_REQ:{
            for(i = 0 ; i < count; i++)
                insert_into_adj_list(&sendto_list[status.MPI_SOURCE], sendrecv_buffer_int[i], num_nodes);
            break;
            }
            case TAG_PR_DONE:{
                expected_requests++;
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're ending up in a deadlock. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448283/deadlock-with-mpi

Comment: is really openmp tag relevant? I don't see any #pragma.

Comment: Never checking `malloc` return value is asking for segfaults.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory glance over your code looks as if your issue is because your `MPI_Send()` calls are blocking and thus nothing is receiving and freeing them up.

If `(request_list[i][1] > 0)` and `(i!= my_rank)` evaluate to `true` you try to perform 2 `MPI_Send()` operations to process rank `i` but you only have 1 matching `MPI_Recv()` operation in each process, i.e. process rank `i`.

You may want to try changing

```
if(request_list[i][1] > 0) {
    ...
}

if( i != my_rank )
    MPI_Send(&temp_data, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG_PR_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

to

```
if(request_list[i][1] > 0) {
    ...
} else if( i != my_rank ) {
    MPI_Send(&temp_data, 1, MPI_INT, i, TAG_PR_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Note the addition of `else` turning `if` into `else if`. This ensures only 1 `MPI_Send()` operation per process. It does not look like the two `MPI_Send()` operations should be executed if the above conditions are true.

---

Alternatively if you need you could look into [`MPI_Isend()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Isend.html) and [`MPI_Irecv()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Irecv.html). Although I don't think they will solve your problem entirely in this case. I still think you need the `else if` clause.

---

I'd also like to point out in **C** there is no need to cast the return of `malloc()`. This topic has been covered extensively on StackOverflow so I won't dwell on it too long.

You should also check the result of `malloc()` is a valid pointer. It returns `NULL` if an error occured.