# A not safe MPI non-blocking communication example?

Tags: c++, mpi, nonblocking

I am implementing MPI non-blocking communication inside my program. I see on MPI_Isend [man_page](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Isend.3.php), it says:

> A nonblocking send call indicates that the system may start copying data out of the send buffer. The sender should not modify any part of the send buffer after a nonblocking send operation is called, until the send completes.

My code works like this:

```
// send messages
if(s > 0){

    MPI_Requests s_requests[s];
    MPI_Status   s_status[s];

    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i){

        // some code to form the message to send
        std::vector<doubel> send_info;

        // non-blocking send
        MPI_Isend(&send_info[0], ..., s_requests[i]);
    }

    MPI_Waitall(s, s_requests, s_status);
}

// recv info
if(n > 0){    // s and n will match

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

        MPI_Status status;

        // allocate the space to recv info
        std::vector<double> recv_info;

        MPI_Recv(&recv_info[0], ..., status)
    }

}
```

My question is: am I modify the send buffers since they are in the inner curly brackets (the `send_info` vector get killed after the loop finishes)? Therefore, this is not a safe communication mode? Although my program works fine now, I still being suspected. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It means don't modify it from a another thread while you're inside the `send` method. You aren't doing that.

Comment: your buffer is/might be allocated on the stack, and hence can be overwritten before it is sent. That looks like a wrong usage of `MPI_Isend()` to me.

Comment: Yeah. I use `std::vector` so it is allocated on stack. So the right way is to put `MPI_Wait()` and `MPI_Isend()` in the same loop?

Comment: yes, that is one option, but likely equivalent to a blocking `MPI_Send()`. Other options include allocating a giant buffer before the `for` loop, and a single `MPI_Waitall()` after. An other common technique is to use 2 buffers: `isend(buffer0);isend(buffer1);wait(req0);isend(buffer(0);wait(req1); ...` so you still have some room for overlap between computation and communication while keeping your memory usage reasonable.

Comment: Note you are unlikely to see any errors with short messages (sent in eager mode) but more likely to send incorrect data with large messages.

Comment: I see, use two buffers for non-blocking send could ba a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points I want to emphasize in this example.

The first one is the problem I questioned: send buffer gets modified before `MPI_Waitall`. The reason is what Gilles said. And the solution could be allocated a big buffer before the `for loop`, and use `MPI_Waitall` after the loop is finished or put `MPI_Wait` inside the loop. But the latter one is equivalent to use `MPI_Send` in the sense of performance.

However, I found if you simply transfer to blocking send and receive, a communication scheme like this could cause deadlock. It is similar to the classic deadlock:

```
if (rank == 0) {
      MPI_Send(..., 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Recv(..., 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 } else if (rank == 1) {
      MPI_Send(..., 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Recv(..., 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 }
```

And the explaination could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20448445/13030001).

My program could cause a similar situation: all the processors called `MPI_Send` then it is a deadlock.

So my solution is to use a large buffer and stick to non-blocking communication scheme.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

// send messages
if(s > 0){

    MPI_Requests s_requests[s];
    MPI_Status   s_status[s];

    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>> send_info;

    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i){


        // some code to form the message to send
        send_info[i] = std::vector<double> ();

        // non-blocking send
        MPI_Isend(&send_info[i][0], ..., s_requests[i]);
    }

    MPI_Waitall(s, s_requests, s_status);
}

// recv info
if(n > 0){    // s and n will match

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

        MPI_Status status;

        // allocate the space to recv info
        std::vector<double> recv_info;

        MPI_Recv(&recv_info[0], ..., status)
    }

}
```